# Unstable wireless Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04, ralink

The internet connection is relatively stable however it seems to drop every few minutes for 10-20 seconds.

Panda Ultra Wireless N Unstable Connection

[http://www.amazon.com/Panda-Ultra-Wireless-Adapter-150Mbps/product-reviews/B00762YNMG](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00762YNMG)

```
    ======== Wireless-Info START ========

System-Info ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

tsohG 3.13.0-34-generic x86_64,  Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, trusty

CPU    : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770K CPU @ 3.50GHz
Memory : 15995 MB
Uptime : 08:46:02 up 24 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.76, 0.85, 0.74


lspci ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169


lsusb ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b38:0010 Gear Head 107-Key Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 047f:c010 Plantronics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


PCMCIA Card Info ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~



iwconfig ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Nehtgaer"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: <MAC C-01 Nehtgaer>   
          Bit Rate=19.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=39/70  Signal level=-71 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:202  Invalid misc:421   Missed beacon:0



rfkill ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

      Interface        Soft blocked  Hard blocked
0: phy0: Wireless LAN      no            no


lsmod ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

rt2800usb              27034  0 
rt2x00usb              20742  1 rt2800usb
rt2800lib              89076  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              55307  3 rt2x00usb,rt2800lib,rt2800usb
mac80211              630653  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb,rt2800lib
cfg80211              484040  2 mac80211,rt2x00lib
crc_ccitt              12707  1 rt2800lib


module parameters ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

cfg80211      (2): cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz=N | ieee80211_regdom=00
mac80211      (5): beacon_loss_count=7 | ieee80211_default_rc_algo=minstrel_ht | max_nullfunc_tries=2 | max_probe_tries=5 | probe_wait_ms=500
rt2800usb     (1): nohwcrypt=N


nm-tool ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

State: unknown
================o======o========o========o=========o===========o==============o===========
 Interface & ID | Type | Driver | State  | Default | Speed     | Support      | HW Addr   
================o======o========o========o=========o===========o==============o===========
                |      |        |        |         |           |              |           
----------------+------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+--------------+-----------


NetworkManager.state ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true


NetworkManager.conf ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false


NM WiFi Profiles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Nehtgaer             : ssid=Nehtgaer | mac-address=<MAC wlan0> | ipv6=ignore | ipv4=auto 


interfaces ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

resolv.conf ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

nameserver 192.168.1.1


Routes & Ping ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.702/1.402/2.103/0.701 ms

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.760/0.820/0.881/0.066 ms


iw reg get ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

(Region : "en_US.UTF-8")
country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS


iwlist chan ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

wlan0     14 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 (2.412 GHz) - 14 (2.484 GHz)

          Current Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)


iwlist scan ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC C-01 Nehtgaer>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=39/70  Signal level=-71 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"Nehtgaer"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000001ea5926265
                    Extra: Last beacon: 44ms ago


blacklist ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci


modinfo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[rt2800usb]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800usb.ko
firmware:       rt2870.bin
version:        2.3.0
srcversion:     D6F814DAF78F2BEA3DA12CB
depends:        rt2x00lib,rt2800lib,rt2x00usb
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (bool)

[rt2x00usb]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00usb.ko
version:        2.3.0
srcversion:     44768071492503F8EFE1EED
depends:        rt2x00lib,mac80211

[rt2800lib]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800lib.ko
version:        2.3.0
srcversion:     9BD0087B6943A41E7FD8EDA
depends:        rt2x00lib,mac80211,crc-ccitt

[rt2x00lib]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00lib.ko
version:        2.3.0
srcversion:     CC69EE39E7D673974A21C0A
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-34-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
srcversion:     8ADA881D348148A3358334C
depends:        cfg80211
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-34-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
srcversion:     E786D076B61F97809B04B64
depends:        
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

[crc_ccitt]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-34-generic/kernel/lib/crc-ccitt.ko
srcversion:     2294FCAD06D727386004EEB
depends:        


udev rules ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC eth0>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# USB device 0x:0x (rt2800usb)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC wlan0>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"


Custom files/entries ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/etc/modules        : Default
/etc/rc.local       : Default
/etc/modprobe.d     : Not Default
/etc/pm/(cnf|pw|sl) : Default

[/etc/modprobe.d]
iwlwifi.conf      : options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
mlx4.conf         : softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en


Kernel boot line ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-34-generic root=UUID=758c9891-4c05-4596-9083-f799581dc1d8 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7


dmesg ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[    0.433570] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.00 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
[    0.433771] audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
[    0.694234] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
[   10.255221] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 5390, rev 0502 detected
[   10.283322] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rf: Info - RF chipset 5370 detected
[   15.248447] init: network-manager main process (852) terminated with status 127
[   15.248457] init: network-manager main process ended, respawning
[   16.236485] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   24.173407] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt2870.bin'
[   24.205183] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.29
[   24.438982] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   35.087206] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   36.177441] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   38.186311] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC C-01 Nehtgaer>
[   38.208811] wlan0: send auth to <MAC C-01 Nehtgaer> (try 1/3)
[   38.210285] wlan0: authenticated
[   38.210322] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC C-01 Nehtgaer> by local choice (reason=3)
[   38.214082] wlan0: associate with <MAC C-01 Nehtgaer> (try 1/3)
[   38.217397] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC C-01 Nehtgaer> (capab=0x421 status=0 aid=1)
[   38.224128] wlan0: associated
[   38.224152] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready

    ======== Done ========
```

Comment: can you append the output of `iw reg get`

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/pm/power.d/wireless
```

you will probably have to install su,:

```
(this will create or edit a configuration file that will override the default power management behavior) and enter the following:

#!/bin/sh
/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

above exit0, then save gedit, close

Do:

```
echo "options rt2800usb nohwcrypt=y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rt2800usb.conf 
sudo modprobe -rfv rt2800usb 
sudo modprobe -v rt2800usb
```

Reboot

In your router change the encryption to WPA2-AES it is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you will probably have better luck with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz. You also will have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: [IPV6](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png)

Check to see if power management is off now by running:

```
iwconfig
```

Comment: Please dont' disable IPv6, just because of a cargo cult. At least explain why. Diagnose the problem first. It would be nice to see the output of `ip monitor` during the loss event, and maybe even `tcpdump -Uni wlan0` if the latter is not private.

Comment: @pilona there is nothing cultist about it, IPV6 is well none to cause issues with wireless when dealing with linux, but it is getting better.

Comment: Please be specific. It may be fine to *temporarily experiment* with that, and roll back if no change for that isolated tweak, or further delve if it causes no improvement. I've used IPv6 over Wi-Fi without issues due to the combination of the two or IPv6 itself. Other people have had supposedly bad experiences. None of these is *necessarily* related to user273047.